# Сохранение отcортированного списка TreeView через SQLite

Tags: python, tkinter, сортировка, sqlite3, save

Ребята, подскажите - есть ли возможность после того, как при нажатии на столбец у меня отсортировался список в TreeView, затем сохранить этот вариант его отображения при следующем перезапуске? Т.к. при перезапуске программы снова не отсортированный. Сохраняется в bd Sqlite3. Буду рад ссылке, что надо почитать...
Сортируется следующим образом:

```
def sort(col, reverse):
    l = [(tree_games.set(k, col), k) for k in tree_games.get_children("")]
    l.sort(reverse=reverse)
    for index, (_, k) in enumerate(l):
        tree_games.move(k, "", index)
    tree_games.heading(col, command=lambda: sort(col, not reverse))

tree_games.heading('Name', text='Name', command=lambda: sort(0, False))
tree_games.heading('Platform', text='Platform', command=lambda: sort(1, False))
tree_games.heading('Fan', text='Fan', command=lambda: sort(2, False))
```

Comment: Например, в базе добавить колонку, в которой сохраняете порядок (номер строки) в отображаемой таблице. После получения сортировать по этой колонке, при закрытии обновлять во всех строках номер строки. Либо просто сделать конфиг, в котором сохранять способ сортировки.